# Call web services ONLY from client side

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a web based application that uses lot of client side requests in various .asmx files.

I am wondering if I can use those web services only from client side and restrict the requests from other sources.

The reason for this is because I want to use those web services only from the current application and to restrict requests from other sources. For security reasons I could use soap authentication but since I requested the services from client side, I don't think the authentication it matters.

I'll appreciate any comments.

Thanks

Comment: All the requests are made from a client. Do you mean that you want to restrict the requests from an Webpage/JS application?

Comment: If I copy and paste the web service url in the browser, I will see the service methods. If someone wants. could easily access them. How can I block this action?

Comment: Ok, so for what are the other methods used for? None public, only internal stuff?

Comment: @StrouMfios You can't (block this action). Webservice has no way of knowing who will attempt to contact/use it. The only thing the webservice can do is try to make sure that whoever does contact it is authorised to do it (after the connection is made).

Comment: The methods are public. I afraid that I couldn't :). I'll try to do the same by using another approach. Perhaps by using handlers

Answer (score 0):

The webservices are by definition public, publicly visible and available (unless they run on private network or standalone computer). I.e. anybody can access them. So, just deploying a webservice and hoping for the best is not a good approach.
And how do you intend to restrict other access?

Comment: That's what I am asking. If you have any suggestion, please share it. I am thinking to do the same by using handlers instead of web serives, but I haven't implement it yet and I don't know if it'll we a good approach